# Depois de atualizar o SDK, meu projeto apareceu com erros

Tags: android, eclipse

Depois que atualizei o SDK e baixei a nova versão do Eclipse, deu erros na src e gen do meu projeto, não faço a mínima ideia do que possa ser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Sua pergunta está ampla demais. Poderia, ao menos, postar os erros?

Comment: Perdão, achei que seria desnecessário postar os erros já que poderia ser algum problema que não seja no código. Mas segue aqui um print dos erros : http://suman.com.br/erros.png

Comment: Tente fazer clean ao projeto. `Project=>clean...`

Comment: Tente voltar a versão e veja se os erros saíram, se não saírem é algum erro nas classes do seu projeto...as vezes o SDK do Android não consegue compilar algo por algum erro no AndroidManifest...dê uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja um erro da classe R.

`R.java` é um arquivo que os plugins do Eclipse Android cria ao construir sua aplicação. `R.java` é criado sob o diretório `"gen"`. Este arquivo é gerado a partir das informações no diretório `"res"`. Se você executar selecione `"Project" -> "Clean ..."` no menu do Eclipse, ele irá remover e, em seguida, gerar o arquivo `R.java`.

O problema `"R cannot be solved"` acontece quando você mudar o seu nome de pacote no arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`. Ele usa o seu nome de pacote Android para criar um subdiretório no diretório `"gen"`, onde ele guarda o arquivo `R.java`.

O Eclipse também pode ter problemas de execução limpa, porque ele fica confuso sobre onde está o arquivo `R.java` depois você mudou o nome do pacote Android.
Você pode mudar o nome do subdiretório no gen para combinar com seu novo nome do pacote, ou você pode mudar o seu nome de pacote de volta para o nome antigo. Faça o limpo e, em seguida, mudar o nome do pacote para o novo nome que você quiser. Isso funciona melhor se você parar que o Eclipse fique tentando dar um build enquanto você está alterando o nome do pacote.

Sob o menu "Project" desmarque a opção "Construir Automaticamente" e também quando o "Clean ..." pergunta se ele deve "Iniciar uma compilação imediatamente" desmarque a caixa para que ele **não tente construir enquanto você está mudando o nome do pacote**. Depois de ter alterado o nome você pode deixar "Build Automatically" novamente.

Observe que, se o seu nome de pacote de arquivos AndroidManifest.xml não corresponde ao seu nome do pacote Java, Eclipse vai acabar adicionando automaticamente uma `"importação <seu Android pacote name> R;."` linha em todos os seus arquivos `java.` que têm quaisquer referências a `R.` Se você mudar de nome do pacote AndroidManifest.xml, às vezes Eclipse não atualiza todas estas importações adicionais. Se isso acontecer, use o **refactoring** do Eclipse `(ALT + Shift + R)` para alterar a declaração de importação em um dos seus arquivos Java para o seu novo nome do pacote AndroidManifest.xml. Lembre-se, é  melhor fazer isso enquanto você tiver desativado o "Build Automatically".